# Android vs Linux for embedded touchscreen application

Tags: android, linux

I'm look at a embedded project that needs a LCD multitouch screen, LCD driver, a webkit browser, Avahi, a web server, and our engine written in C++.

Android on first glance looks like it has most of the right components out of the box with the least modification... But the use of a JVM seems to be heavyweight for a small memory footprint embedded device (128-196MB min) and besides our code is C++. It looks like you can't yank the JVM out because major OS components are running in Java (true?).

Linux appears to have most of the pieces that can be put together, without the unnecessary cruft. Here are the major questions:

- Once the GUI pieces are put together, is linux still a significantly smaller memory footprint than Android assuming the the JVM and application components in Android aren't useful to the project (right now our GUI-less linux build is around 24MB)?
- Can Android be run without the JVM components to reduce memory footprint if you don't need any user applications running in Java?
- Can you write first class C++ applications in Android?
- Does linux have a mature multitouch interface with system-wide touch keyboard, touch GUI, touchable broswer gestures (scroll, zoom, etc). Or does it require a lot of custom UI coding?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question: but have you ever looked at buildroot? http://buildroot.uclibc.org/ I've used it as the basis for most of my embedded platforms and its package list is pretty large.  Though, i've never designed a system with a GUI. Maybe a glance at what it offers will give you an idea of what you'd have to create by hand with a non-android solution? FWIW

Comment: android is a linux based os http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29

Comment: @Ray, that answers none of his questions.  Put emphasis on "Once the GUI pieces are put together".  He wants a comparison of Android with Linux+Z, and he doesn't know what Z is, or if it exists.

Comment: @Ray Obviously I realize android is linux based. While it has the functionality, it appears to me that the java umbrella of components is unextractable from the OS while still leaving it functional (could be wrong here). Java and a JVM runtime makes sense in a managed OS full of multi vendor applications. But is a lot of cruft for an tightly controlled embedded system. So I'm looking for a touch OS solution that is similarly elegant without the java.

Comment: this may be of ineterest: http://mobile.slashdot.org/story/12/02/21/1744201/canonical-puts-ubuntu-on-android-smartphones

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Native_development_kit and http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

Comment: I would just go with Android for a modern, tactile user experience.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of misconceptions in your post. I'm going to start by enumerating your questions and answers:

- Once the GUI pieces are put together, is linux still a significantly smaller memory footprint than Android assuming the the JVM and application components in Android aren't useful to the project (right now our GUI-less linux build is around 24MB)?

That all depends on what window manager you choose to use. My instinct here is anything with close to mature touch support at this point is going to be as heavy or heavier than android.

- Can Android be run without the JVM components to reduce memory footprint if you don't need any user applications running in Java?

Android does not use JVM. Android uses the java language, but uses the dalvik virtual machine which is designed for embedded devices. The commonality ends at the fact that they're virtual machines.

- Can you write first class C++ applications in Android?

You can write large portions of your app in C or C++ using the NDK, however, any module written that way needs to be called through an android written using the java/dalvik SDK. That way, any performance critical module such as doing extensive calculations can be native, but the gui layer would not be (although usually with a GUI layer performance is less likely to be a concern). The native android windowing and UI libraries are written in Java, you would have to redo much of the work to get usable UI elements in the NDK as Google didn't intend the NDK for that.

My advice here is to prototype the app using the normal SDK, leave stubs for anything that would benefit from hardware acceleration (Keep it modular so it's not too interdependent)

- Does linux have a mature multitouch interface with system-wide touch keyboard, touch GUI, touchable broswer gestures (scroll, zoom, etc). Or does it require a lot of custom UI coding?

Depends on the window manager you use. No matter what you choose you'll likely need to fool around until you find viable combinations of everything. There is no one great integrated distro solution that I know of (although others may). My impression of the lay of the land is that there's not a lot done on this front.

The final thing I want to add is well written java code executing in Dalvik (or even JVM) can run close to the speed of native code. If you know what you're doing and understand when something is a reference, what collection types to use for what purpose (hint: Not everything is an array), and aren't replicating objects all over the place, Java is pretty good.

Comment: Dalvik is just one JVM implementation. It is still a Java based virtual machine. A typical benchmark for Java vs C shows a 2-3x reduction in performance at a 3x (or more) increase in RAM use. This is not surprising as it is a virtual machine and uses automatic garbage collection. Even if it wasn't a VM, the garbage collection dooms it to a compromise between ram and speed. Anyways losing 3x performance at 3x RAM is an expensive tradeoff for an embedded device

Comment: Dalvik is not a JVM implementation at all. The byte code is completely different. When creating an android application the application is first compiled to Java byte code, then to Dalvik byte-code. The two are not compatible as that's what being a JVM implementation would imply.

Comment: I didn't argue that it isn't a virtual machine at all, just that it isn't a Java virtual machine. The JVM spec is a bytecode specification. Dalvik bytecode is not compatible with JVM bytecode. I'm not sure what's unclear to you about that, but that's just how it is. I'm also not sure why, almost a year later you're still here arguing about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not talking from experience, but take a look at http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/kde-spark-tablet-opens-pre-order-registration/ or even easier at https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+touch+interface

So yes, Linux has support for touch. Not sure about multi-touch though, as far as i know its there(but i have 0 experience).

As for scrolling and zooming, i guess it will all depend on what you use in the back. The real question should be if webkit supports smooth-scrolling and zooming(if you plan to run your application in a browser as i understand).